# How to program Arduino LCD shield with Python?

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-uno, lcd

so I want to run a Arduino LCD shield with Python code..But after having some research on the Internet, I can not found any tutorial, some just give some basic code with LED.

And one things that how can I add a LCD library (LyquidCrystal.h in Arduino code) if i program in Python.

Thank you guys very much.

Comment: Please ask this question here : https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's not an Arduino, if you can program it in Python.

Comment: @datafiddler Oh really ! I just wondering if there are any ways to do that, because I am doing a small project that using Python, so its good if I can program Arduino in Python language.

Comment: Duplicated in https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/70429/how-to-program-arduino-lcd-shield-with-python, and even got an answer there

Comment: Not sure if, for the benefit of using Python, it's worth  to overcomplicate that "small project". But that's better discussed in your arduino.stackexchange.com thread